# Combinatorial proof of $P_r^n = \frac{n}{n-r}P_r^{n-1}$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I'm trying to extract the combinatorial meaning of the following identity:

$$P_r^n = \frac{n}{n-r}P_r^{n-1}, r < n$$

Where $P_r^n$ denotes the number of r-permutations of a set of n elements

I first attempted to solve this throught double-counting. $P_r^{n-1} $ denotes the r-permutations of (n-1)-subsets of N, where |N| = n. As there are ${n \choose n-1} = n$ subsets of N, summing over all r-permutations of such subsets should give the number of r-permutations of N, and thus:

$$P_r^n = nP_r^{n-1}$$

Which is obviously wrong; I have little idea how do I make sense of the missing $\frac{1}{n-r}$ term in a combinatorial manner.

This problem originally comes from a combinatorics textbook, "Principles and Techniques in Combinatorics", though without the requirement of a strictly combinatorial proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What makes you think that summing over $r$ permutations from a subset with $n-1$ elements will give you the number of $r$ permutations from the set of $n$ elements? You are clearly overcounting here.

Take a simple set $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$. Suppose we were to count the number of $2$-permutations of this. One of the permutations possible is $\{1,2\}$. Now, notice that in your method, this permutation is counted twice, once for the subset $\{1,2,3\}$ and another time for the subset $\{1,2,4\}$. The same can be said for every other permutation.

Generalizing, for a set of $n$- elements, if we need to calculate $r$-permutations, then, in your summation, each permutation shall be counted $\binom {n-r}{n-r-1}=(n-r)$ times, since this is the number of $(n-1)$-subsets possible which will contain the $r$- elements. Hence division by $(n-r)$ is required to avoid overcounting. Now you will obtain the expected result.

Comment: I realized i was overcounting, though not exactly by a factor of (n-r). Your answer made it clear now. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Oh I meant to say "though didn't know how (n-r) solved the overcounting problem" instead of "though not exactly by a factor of (n-r)", as ofc my original solution overcounts by a factor (n-r).

Comment: Yes, I understood what you meant.